# finding perfect numbers from mersenne primes - very strange outcome

Tags: r

can you please help me with where my function is going wrong? I want to create a function which lists the perfect numbers up to 2^N -1 using the fact that if q is a Mersenne prime (a prime number of the form 2^p − 1 where p is also prime) then q(q + 1)/2 is a perfect number. I have made 4 functions: one to find factors, one to find primes, one to find Mersenne primes, and then one to find perfect numbers. They all seem to work fine, until I let N=4 in my last function: it gives me the first 4 perfect numbers and last correctly, however the penultimate one isn't a perfect number.

Please could someone let me know where I'm going wrong?

```
factorlist<-function(n){
if (n<2){return("Invalid input")}
if (n%%1!=0){return("Invalid input")}
vec<-0
for(i in 1:(n-1)){
if (n%%i==0){
vec[length(vec)]<-i
vec<-c(vec,0)
}
}
vec<-vec[-length(vec)]
return(vec)
}

prime <- function(n){
  primeR <- function(p, i = 1){
    f <- p %% p[i] == 0 & p != p[i]
    if (any(f)){
      p <- primeR(p[!f], i+1)
    }
    p
  }
  primeR(2:n)
}

MersenneNumber<-function(n){
  vec<-c(0)
  for (i in 3:n){
    vec<-union(vec, c(2^prime(i)-1))
  }
  return(vec[-length(1)])
}

MersennePerfect<-function(N){
 vec<-0
   for (i in 3:(2^N-1)){
     vec<-union(vec, c((MersenneNumber(i)*(MersenneNumber(i)+1))/2))
 }
 return(vec[-length(1)])
}
```

MersennePerfect(4) gives   6, 28, 496, 8128 (all perfect), 2096128 (not perfect), 33550336 (perfect).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you generate all of the numbers of the form `2^p - 1`   but you do not check whether or not they are prime.  This only works for *primes* of the form `2^p-1`  Your first failure,  2096128, is for p=11 that is for 2047*2048/2   But 2047 = 23 *89 is not prime.

Comment: Of course, thank you. Could I apply my prime function to the numbers of the form 2^p -1 or would I have to create a new function? This seems like a long method in hindsight.

Comment: You could use your prime function, at least indirectly.  If I understand correctly, your prime function returns all primes up to and including the number. To check if q is prime, you can just use `q %in% prime(q)`

Comment: Thank you very much! I assume I want an if clause in my MersennePerfect function? Something like if(q %in% prime(q)) ? And then work out q(q+1)/2 ? Sorry, I'm very new to R.

Comment: Yes.  That is what you need to do.

Comment: Hmm, I seem to now get an "Error in 2:n : NA/NaN argument". Any idea why this comes up?

Comment: It sounds like n is undefined.  But it is hard to tell without seeing how you have now changed the code.

Comment: I realize this is very messy and am not sure what inout I should use for my new if clause. Tidying up would be in order: `MersennePerfect<-function(N){
   vec<-0
      for (i in 3:(2^N-1)){
   if(MersenneNumber(N) %in% prime(MersenneNumber(N)){
  vec<-union(vec, c((MersenneNumber(i)*(MersenneNumber(i)+1))/2))
   }
   return(vec[-length(1)])
  }
  }`

Comment: The problem is that some of your functions work on vectors and others only scalars. Note in particular that `if` works only on a single conditional,  not a vector of conditionals.      At this point,  I am going to leave it to you to debug the rest.